# Focus on Input Field on Modal Open

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, focus, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that opens on page load. I need to set the focus on the textbox. I tried using several codes that I had searched but It does not work. Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show', function() {
        $('#keyword', this).focus();
    });

});
```

And my input field is this

```
<input type="text" style="width: 50%; margin-left:2px; " id="keyword"               class="input-group inline form-control search" name="keyword" placeholder="Search" ng-model="keyword" ng-required="true" required >
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, just change `.on("show"` into `.on("shown.bs.modal"` :D

See further reference about bootstrap's modal events here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

**EDIT:**

This should work like you want: :D Sorry I wasn't read your question carefully ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //to have your input focused every your modal open
    $('#myModal').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
        $('#keyword').focus();
    });

    //to open the modal when document is ready
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

**Addition:**

If you want to focus on first `.form-control` inside the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
        $(this).find(".form-control:first").focus();
    });
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: When I use this, the modal didn't show when i load the page

Comment: ah, sorry, I didn't read your question completely :"D I'll edit my answer